# TypeORM with MySQL Error: Pool is closed. Test is getting stuck when calling the Database

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

we're having a weird issue with TypeORM, specifically with Jest(might be related, might not be). A certain test is getting completely stuck/hung and we’re having a hard time figuring out what the issue is.

In terms of stack: `Typescript, NodeJS, Apollo Graphql, Jest, MySQL`.
The test in question is actually an integration test using Apollo’s integration test framework.

What happened first is that a specific test just completely got stuck, and after several long minutes an error is thrown in the console: `QueryFailedError: ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

Trying to pinpoint the problem led me to a function we run on `afterEach` which “destroys” the database. It initially ran:

```
await queryRunner.query('DELETE FROM Table1');
await queryRunner.query('DELETE FROM Table2');
...
```

The error and "deadlock" was initially fixed after I changed it from `queryRunner` to `queryBuilder`:

```
await queryBuilder.delete().from('Table1').execute();
...
```

This was done after fidgeting around with `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` and with `SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS;` to try figuring out what was happening. I also changed the transaction isolation to READ-COMMITTED but to no avail. Nothing really worked except changing it from `queryRunner` to `queryBuilder`.

This worked for a bit but now it seems like the test is getting stuck again (The test hasn’t changed but the code it’s testing **has**). Now after the test hangs, we get this error: `Error: Pool is closed`. Afterwards the test is "released" and all the tests just start failing one by one.

We found out that this is the sequence of events that causes the test to get stuck:

```
1. open a transaction with queryRunner
2. perform a read query
3. then perform a write
4. commit the transaction and release the queryRunner
5. delete the DB
6. perform a write - deadlock
```

Furthermore we noticed the following:

> If we make sure that we only use the queryRunner for updates, and not
> for queries, then the deadlock doesn’t happen.
>
> Changing the code such that we first make all of the read queries with the regular connection
> object (not queryRunner) **and only then** if we connect with
> `queryRunner` and make all of the writes - then the deadlock does not happen.

Does anyone have any insight as to what might be going on? Is there some instability with queryRunner or some specific things we need to take into account when using it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I was faced same issue and my problem was unhandled async/await.
Check if some promise object is not handled.
If you use async keyword, you must handle all async functions using await keyword.
Also don't forget calling `done` method of [jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous).

Comment: His problem is with database lock, so I don't believe it has anything to do with `async/await`

Comment: I had the same issue with an error `Pool is closed` the reason of which was forgot `await` keyword. Thus, the connection was closed before the actual end of function execution.

Comment: Also use `mysql2/promise` which allows you to use `await` in the first place, otherwise you need to write callbacks everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using just `mysql2` without promises (thus not using `mysql2/promise), which I now regret. I should have use Promises since day 1.

Anyway, most likely you do have a raise condition that your database was still open (and not closed) while Jest was finished.

If you have a test-case that is executing a fast `getConnection` method for example. Like:

```
this.dbPool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
  if (err) {
    debug('server')('There is a database connection problem, error: ' + err.message + ' (code: ' + err.errno + ').')
    console.error(err)
  }
  if (conn) {
    conn.release()
  }
})
```

This will lead to issues. After all your (unit) test could be finish and Jest could be done, while this callback method was still running. Hence the reason I mentioned it's better to move to `mysql2/promise` and use `await` in your production code. Ps. same is true for promises/callbacks in your Jest test code.

Answer (score 0):

`Pool is closed` - can also appear when keyword `await` is missed somewhere in code. So, you are probably trying to `destroy()` when some requests are not finished to execute yet.

As a partial workaround, try to put:

```
await AppDataSource.destroy();
```

Inside timeout:

```
  setTimeout(async () => {
    await AppDataSource.destroy();
  }, 0);
```

But this is still partial. Better solution is to detect a line where `await` was missed.